# Subdomain cookie sharing in Rails 3 is not working (on Heroku)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, heroku, subdomain

I'm trying to have cookies on my site dapshare.com work for both the root address and the 'www' subdomain.

A lot of other stackoverflow answers (and the great Railscasts vid on this topic) have suggested adding this line to session_store.rb:

```
Dapshare::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_dapshare_session', :domain => :all
```

This doesn't seem to make a difference: if I log in at dapshare.com, I still am not logged in at www.dapshare.com.

Am I doing something wrong here? I am using the following code to store information in the cookie:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:thing_to_store] = store_information
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should be able to view the cookie in your browser settings, what does it say there that the `domain` property is set to?

Comment: Interesting.  Just logged in at www.dapshare.com.  It created at 'remember_token' for www.dapshare.com, but created a '_dapshare_session' for dapshare.com.  Does that mean the code I'm using above (cookies.permanent...) is not picking up the session_store domain?

Comment: (btw, the remember_token is what I'm using to store the logged in user's identity)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: using the 'cookies[:new_cookie] =' does not seem to grab the domain from the session_store config settings.

I added the :domain to the new cookie and it now works:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:new_cookie] = {:value => new_value, :domain => ".dapshare.com"}
```

For anyone else reading, you also need to specify the domain when deleting the cookie

```
cookies.delete :new_cookie, :domain => ".dapshare.com"
```

(Thanks for your help with diagnosis Andrew Marshall.)

Comment: What if I want this default for all my cookies?  There's no config that just..does this for you?  :(

Comment: Not that I've found - I still use the approach listed in my answer. Let me know if you come up with something, though!

Answer (score 5):

You can actually just specify your cookies using domain => :all instead of domain => '.dapshare.com' in Rails 3.1 +:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:new_cookie] = {:value => new_value, :domain => :all}
```

This more flexible than outright specifying a string domain.  Now your application won't break on a different production domain.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue, when passing :all doesn't seems to work properly. If you want to use only for subdomains try the following:

```
Dapshare::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_dapshare_session', :domain => '.dapshare.com'
```

Comment: Thanks dombesz - I tried that with no luck actually.  The _dapshare_session cookie would save at dapshare.com, but the code I was using to store the cookie (see the question) kept saving to www.dapshare.com.  I've fixed the problem now by explicitly stating the domain when setting the cookie.